# Hard time understanding Java Consumer Example

Tags: java, lambda, consumer

I don't understand the method declaration in an example regarding the Java Consumer interface. I found this example in an online-book ([Listing 11.7](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel/11_007.html)). 
It says:

```
class Consumers {

    public static <T> Consumer<T> measuringConsumer( Consumer<T> block){
        return t -> {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            block.accept( t );
            long duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Execution time (ns): " + duration);
        };
    }
}
```

In the declaration what does `<T> Consumer<T>` mean? Shouldn't there be just `Consumer<T>` without the first `<T>`?

Comment: What happens if you remove the first `<T>`?

Comment: I am sure that you can remove the first <T>. The Consumer<T> it's the definition for Consumer tigh generic type T which must be the same type as the one in the accept() method and measuringConsumer() method take as input.

Comment: @DinaBogdan ehm no, you **cannot** remove the `<T>` - I mean, you can *technically* remove it but then it will not compile.

Comment: `measuringConsumer` is a generic method read the following if this is new to you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 4):

that first `<T>` is used to define the bounds of the type of objects `Consumer` will accept.

in this particular case, the method appears to accept anything that derives from `java.lang.Object`, but you could use it to further constrain acceptable types by doing something like this:

```
public static <T extends Foo> Consumer<T> measuringConsumer(Consumer<T> block) { ... }
```

refer to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

The first `<T>` is a *generic type variable*. It indicates that the `measuringConsumer` method is *generic*, i.e. that it accepts and/or returns a generic type.

In this case, the method accepts an argument of type `Consumer<T>` (a generic type), and it returns a value fo type `Consumer<T>`, which is also generic. Most important, the generic type of the return value is of the **same generic type of the argument**. This means that if you pass a `Consumer<Integer>` as an argument, this method will return a `Consumer<Integer>` and not i.e. a `Consumer<String>`, because the `T` type variable is the same for both the argument and the return value.

Note that the type variable `T` is not bounded. This means that `T` can be anything, i.e. you can pass a `Consumer` of anything as an argument, such as `Consumer<Integer>`, `Consumer<Double>`, `Consumer<String>`, `Consumer<YourOwnClass>`, etc.

If `T` were bounded, i.e. `<T extends Number>`, then `Consumer<T>` could only be `Consumer<Integer>`, `Consumer<Long>`, `Consumer<BigDecimal>`, `Consumer<Double>`, etc, in fact, `Consumer` of any descendant of `Number`.